# What is the best way to get output of script on another server?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, exec, nominatim

I have Nominatim (with open street maps) installed on a server.

On another server I have a database with multiple columns 3 of which are lat(latitude), lon (longitude) and address. The lat and lon columns are completed with coordinates and for the 3rd column I've written a script in PHP which queries Nominatim (on the other server) to get the address for the coordinates and updates the database when ran. At the moment the script uses cUrl ( creates the url like `.../reverse.php?lat=XX&lon=YY` ), gets the output (an xml) and updates the database.

The problem is that for 1000 coordinates it takes around 16 seconds. The script is running 8 cUrl threads at all time until all the fetching is done. I found that 8 threads is best because the server has an 8 core CPU.

I was wondering if there was a better solution to get the address faster. I was thinking of running exec via ssh or even exporting the database to the nominatim server and running exec there.

Before starting to write the code I wanted to get an opinion so I don't write a few hundreds of lines of code to get a worse result.

Comment: I can't imagine your geocoding queries to be CPU-bound. Consider increasing the disk throughput of your server instead.

Comment: I was looking at an improvement without changing the server components. Is there something better (rather than exec or curl) that I could do to decrease the time? I implemented this morning an script with exec and got ~32 seconds for 1000 coordinates which is double of what I was getting with cURL.

Comment: That's impossible to tell without knowing what your current bottleneck is.

Comment: Threads should not be the issue. You can download as many as your bandwidth can take. The problem is more likely to be hanging connections. CURL will process all your URLs as a batch, and not move to the next batch until all are downloaded. To download parallel URLS, look at the puf program, which is in UB repositories.

Second, can you not do something to make multiple lookups in one request? Like: /reverse.php?lat[]=XX&lon[]=YY&lat[]=XX&lon[]=YY&lat[]=XX&lon[]=YY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the time down to 4 seconds by moving the script on the Nominatim server and using execs to run 8 scripts, each handling 1/8 of the data.